# Unable to join Ubuntu 22.04 system into Domain (AD)

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu

Can someone help me how to join an Ubuntu 22.04 system to a domain? I tried all the steps and procedures that are available on the internet. Below are the observations

- Unable to receive ping response to FQDN
- Able to ping Domain IP
- While discovering domain getting error : No such realm found
- Unable to install sssd packages
- The followed process sucessfully working and able to join the systems in Domain in 20.04

Regards,
Shaik